# Is it possible to do object recognition of a movie file (mp4, mov,...)

Tags: image, image-recognition, movie

Is it possible to do object recognition of a movie file (mp4, mov,...)?

For example, stream a movie and look for objects or people and determine who the person is or what products are in the movie?

Would the process boil down to taking many snapshots of the image buffer and processing them as normal images?

I am totally new to this, sorry if this question may makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this project which does exactly what I was looking for.

https://sites.google.com/site/igormarinescu/home/projects/objectsrec

It's done in realtime, so I will review the code.